# Error de salida de div con JSPDF

Tags: javascript, html5, jspdf

Estoy realizando un proyecto en el que tengo que desplegar una tabla que estoy iterando desde unas etiquetas `<div>`, al aplicar las librerías de JSPDF sin los `<div>` la salida del documento resulta exitosa, muestra todo su contenido.

Pero con las divisiones que se necesitan para recorrer el array traído de la base de datos, solo muestra el footer y el header del pdf mas el contenido de la tabla no se puede observar, anexo documentación y capturas de pantalla de lo sucedido para poderlos contextualizar mejor.

```js
function HTMLtoPDF(){
var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'letter');
const url = '../pdf.php';
source = $('#HTMLtoPDF')[0];
specialElementHandlers = {
 '#bypassme': function(element, renderer){
  return true
 }
}
margins = {
    top: 0,
    left: 55,
    width: 545
  };
pdf.fromHTML(
   source // HTML string or DOM elem ref.
   , margins.left // x coord
   , margins.top // y coord
   , {
    'width': margins.width // max width of content on PDF
    , 'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
   },
   function (dispose) {
     // dispose: object with X, Y of the last line add to the PDF
     //          this allow the insertion of new lines after html
        pdf.save('Reporte de Actividades.pdf');
      }
 )

  
}
```

```css
// Inicio de la seccion Main-tittle


#MainTittle h1{
   text-align: center;
   text-shadow: #666666;
   font-weight: bolder;
   font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
   margin-bottom: 50px;
   margin-top: 20px;
   float: left;
   margin-left: 10%;
}
  #MainTittle dfn {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 15%;
    padding-bottom: 95px;
    
  }


// Fin de laseccion Main-tittle




  
  
  
  .button {
  
        border              : 2px solid #000;                      /* 2 pixeles de borde negro                                                */
        text-align          : center;                              /* Texto centrado                                                          */
        text-decoration     : none;                                /* Sin decoraciones para el texto (por defecto viene con underline)        */
        padding             : 10px;                                /* Un poco de padding para que se vea bien el botón                        */
        /* La transición en el click (:active) tiene que ser rápida 150ms (transform y color), la transición para cambiar de foco en 150ms    */
        transition          : transform 0.15s ease-in-out, color 0.15s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.15s ease-in-out;
        color               : #FFF;                                /* Color del texto en blanco                                               */
        margin              : 10px;                                /* 10 pixeles de margen para separar los botones entre si.                 */
        position            : relative;                            /* Posición relativa para que sus hijos partan desde él                    */
        overflow            : hidden;                              /* Todo lo que sobresalga del botón no se verá                             */
        cursor              : pointer;                             /* Puntero del mouse que muestre una mano                                  */
        transform           : perspective(600px) translateZ(0px) rotateZ(0deg) rotateX(0deg); /* Perspectiva, rotación y posición por defecto */
        text-shadow         : 1px 1px 1px #666;                    /* Una ligera sombra gris para el texto */
        background-color    :#336886;                                 
        width               :200px;                                   /* Asigna un tamaño general para los botones*/
    }
  
  .button:focus {
        outline    : 0px solid transparent;                        /* Elimino el outline que viene por defecto en los button */
        box-shadow : 0px 0px 4px 2px #64bf9c,  0px 0px 2px 1px #64bf9c;  /* Creo uan sombra en gris oscuro con 2 tonalidades       */
    }
  
    .button:active {
      transform : perspective(600px) translateZ(-75px) rotateZ(-0.5deg) rotateX(-10deg); /* Creo el efecto de hundimiento para el botón */
      color     : #BBB;                                                                  /* Cambio el color del texto a gris            */
  }
  [class^='button']:hover, [class^='button']:active { border : 2px solid #64bf9c; }
  
// fin del modulo de la botonera principal  

// inicio de la pestaña descriptiva (tab0) en la que se indica alusuario seleccionar una pestaña

#tab0{
  text-align: center;
  
}

// fin de la pestaña descriptiva (tab0)    



// inicio de la configuracion de los modulos

.modulos{

 

}

// fin de la configuracion de los modulos 



// Inicio del contenedor del pdf 

.card-body{
  background-color: #a0a0a0;
  border-radius: 25px;
  page-break-after: always;
 
} 

.card-body td, thead{
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #000;
  
}


// fin del Contenedor del pdf

// inicio boton descargar

#btn-descargar{
  margin-top: 15%;
  width: 15%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #747373;
  margin-left: 40%;
}


#btn-descargar:hover{
  text-decoration-line: underline;
  transform : perspective(600px) translateZ(-75px) rotateZ(-0.5deg) rotateX(-10deg); /* Creo el efecto de hundimiento para el botón */
  }

// fin boton descargar


// inicio de imagenes institucionales 
#descripcion {
  opacity: 0;
  position: fixed; top: 0%;
 
}


#p1 {
 margin-top: 5%;
 margin-bottom: 0%; 

}

.imagen{
  margin-top: 0%;
  margin-bottom: 5%;
  margin-left: 0%;
 
}

footer{
  opacity: 0;
  
}

// fin de imagenes institucionales

// Inicio animacion de las barras de progreso de actividades 
.active{
  animation: progress-bar-stripes 2s linear infinite;
  background-color:#cc9a03;
  font: bolder;
  }

// Fin animacion de las barras de progreso de actividades 


// inicio de medidas de la tabla del documento PDF
  .enunciado{
    
  }
// Fin de medidas de la tabla del documento PDF


// Inicio de medidas de las columnas y filas de la tabla




td{
 width: 352px;
 text-align: justify;
}

th{
  padding: 1%;
  margin: 1%;
  width: 352px;
  text-align: center;
  border-style: solid; 
  border-color: #000;
  
}   

// Fin de medidas de las columnas y filas de la tabla
```

```html
 <div id="HTMLtoPDF" >
      
           <header>
                    <div id="descripcion">
                     
                             
                                  <img class="imagen" src="../../../assets/images/header.png" alt="">
                             
                                    <p id="p1"> 
                                      Documento generado por el sistema.               
                                    </p>
                                    <p id="p2">En el encontrará el informe que indica el progreso de las actividades docentes.</p>
                              
                        
                    </div>
            </header>

           

        

        
        

      <!--                                            LISTA DE REPORTE DE ACTIVIDADES                                              -->

          


              <div class="card-body table-responsive" >
                      
                      <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped " style="border-color:black;">
                        
                        <thead>
                                 <tr>
                                  
                                  <div > 
                                    <th class="C-Enunciado">Actividades Y Sugerencias</th>
                                    <th class="C-Modulo" >Modulo de la actividad</th>
                                    <th class="C-Progreso" >Progreso % </th>
                                  </div>
                                  
                                                        
                                  
                                </tr>
                            
                              </thead>

                              <tbody  >
                                <tr>
                                <div *ngFor="let pregunta of preguntas">
                                  <div *ngFor="let actividad of actividades">
                                      <div *ngIf="pregunta.id == actividad.fk_id_pregunta" > 
                                                                                        
                                              
                                                  
                                                <td>
                                                    {{pregunta.enunciado}}
                                                </td>  

                                                <td >
                                                  <div *ngFor=" let modulo of modulos">
                                                          <div *ngIf="modulo.id == actividad.fk_id_modulo" >
                                                            {{modulo.nombre}}
                                                          </div>
                                                  </div>
                                                  </td>
                                        

                                                  <td > 
                                                    <div class="container-fluid">
                                                        <br>
                                                        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar"
                                                              aria-valuenow="40" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" [style.width]="porcentaje">
                                                                {{porcentaje}}
                                                        </div>
                                                          
                                                    </div>
                                                    </td>
                                            
                                            
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                  </div>
                                </tr> 
                          </tbody>
                      </table>
                  
                </div>
          
            

            

        
 
   

    <footer>
          <img src="../../../assets/images/footer.png" >
     </footer>

  </div>    
        
      <button class="btn btn-secondary" class="button" onclick="HTMLtoPDF()">descargar PDF</button>
```

[image: Captura de pantalla]